# img srcset based on img width rather than viewport width

Tags: html, srcset

I have a partial template that renders an article on a page which is basically an image and accompanying text.  In a landing page I will have several articles on the page, with varying classes, the lead article will be full width, secondary articles half with, tertiary 3rd width.  Also sometimes sidebar articles will have a very small widths.  And then depending on the viewport, sometimes the image can be rendered above the text or to the left of it.

**In Summary the same article HTML renders in many ways depending on context.**

Is there any way to account for this in the latest srcset spec?

From what I can tell I would have to have a  different sizes attribute per context, essentially coupling layout/breakpoint to the markup which in my implementation with so many contexts, will make the server side logic horrid.

Answer (score 0):

The width descriptor in srcset defines always the width of the image itself not the viewport.

In case you mean the sizes attribute:

In short you can't. The reason for this is, that the browser starts to fetch images before it might fully loaded/parsed stylesheets. This means the layout isn't known. However if you use lazyloading techniques you can automatically calculate the sizes attribute.

This is done by [lazysizes](https://github.com/aFarkas/lazysizes).

Comment: Thanks for your response, hmm I'm a little confused I had an image that had a 10px padding around it, so if the viewport was 1000px the image would be 980px.  If I had an image in srcset with a 1000w setting, it would load it when the viewport was 1000 not 1020.  Based on your final paragraph it could only ever rely on viewport as a guide to which image to download, as the css may not be parsed.

Comment: To illustrate, the 2 images here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZbEvwB will always be the same even though they are different sizes.  The viewport size seems to govern which src gets loaded. If my browser is > 800 they both load 1600, if < 800 they load the 800.

Comment: Two points here: 1. You need to add the sizes attribute. (i.e.: sizes="50vw" and sizes="25vw") otherwise the browser defaults to "100vw" for both images. 2. Chrome checks whether higher resolution images are already cached and selects the cached image if it finds one.

Comment: OK thanks for clarifying that.  It will be impossible for me to account for all the different permutations of my article layout in the sizes tag.  It's a shame you can't force the browser to defer the decision until it knows the size of that the image will take and base it on that, it feels wrong to be putting breakpoint information in markup when you've already defined it in your css.  I get why the browser wants to start loading assets as soon as possible but it would be nice to override this.

Comment: I have worked around this with a script in the bottom of the page which calculates what percent of the viewport the image is taking and setting a size attribute accordingly.  If you set the srcset and sizes attribute at this point it works well.   It does mean non JS clients have no images but I can accept that hit.

Comment: This totally seems to be the case with is kinda BS of the W3C in my opinion in 2020. Why on earth are we determining image size based on the view port instead of on the actual image width? I still need to use Javascript to do this, unless someone has come up with something...

Comment: The reason viewport width is the size basis is because it knows the viewport width for the entire page render, meaning as soon as it finds the `<img/>` tag it can kick off the network request. If it was based on actual width, the request would have to wait until the very end of rendering as there might be CSS at the very bottom that adjusts the image's size. With that, the browser is now no more efficient than your JS src update.